# How do i check which process is reading hard disk?

Tags: hard-drive

Most times when i browse the web there is a lot of irregular hard disk reading: swap is off (sudo swapoff --all) and browser disk cache is turned to 0kb (through firefox disk cache configuration). What can be happening? How do i check which process is doing such hard disk reading? This happens specially when browsing facebook ...

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at `iotop`, exactly like `top` in spirit, but for I/O operations.